# How to skip AsyncLoading with FutureProvider in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to learn riverpod and I am wondering if it is possible to "skip" AsyncLoading if the data of another FutureProvider is already available. Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<Map<String, MyObject>> fetchDataMap(FetchDataMapRef ref) {
    // Fetch data from the network
    return data;
} 

@riverpod
FutureOr<List<MyObject>> dataList(DataListRef ref, List<String> ids) {
    final dataMap = await ref.watch(fetchDataMapProvider.future);
    return ids
      .map((id) => dataMap[id])
      .whereType<MyObject>()
      .toList();
}
```

The first time reading/watching the provider is expected to emit a AsyncLoading object, but pretty much all subsequent calls will have AsyncData, but even if that is the case, when I watch a new dataListProvider, it will return a AsyncLoading regardless of the current state of fetchDataMapProvider.

Is there any way to skip this loading?

I tryed replacing Future with FutureOr and reading the current state before waiting, but AsyncLoading will still be the first state to be emitted.

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<List<MyObject>> dataList(
  DataListRef ref,
  List<String> ids,
) async {
  final future = ref.watch(fetchDataMapProvider.future);
  final currentAsyncValue = ref.read(fetchDataMapProvider);

  final dataMap = currentAsyncValue.valueOrNull ?? await future;

  return ids
      .map((id) => dataMap[id])
      .whereType<MyObject>()
      .toList();
}
```

I also tryed the following:

```dart
@riverpod
AsyncData<List<MyObject>> dataList(
  DataListRef ref,
  List<String> ids,
) async {
  final currentAsyncValue = ref.watch(fetchDataMapProvider);

  return currentAsyncValue.when(
    data: (data) => ids
      .map((id) => dataMap[id])
      .whereType<MyObject>()
      .toList(),
    error: (error, stackTrace) => AsyncError(error, stackTrace),
    loading () => AsyncLoading(),
  );
}
```

But it looks very hacky, and I would loose support for the dataListProvider.future.

Comment: A new provider *must* go through a loading phase.  If you don't want to show that in your UI, you'll still have to do something until you get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: FutureOr is the answer!

After some trials and errors, I have reached to a solution for the problem, since I was using an async function, it would always return a Future and riverpod would have to wait on it even though it had an value already. To fix this all I need to do is to remove the async and return a future:

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<List<MyObject>> dataList(
  DataListRef ref,
  List<String> ids,
) {
  final future = ref.watch(fetchDataMapProvider.future);
  final currentAsyncValue = ref.read(fetchDataMapProvider);

  final dataMap = currentAsyncValue.valueOrNull;

  if(dataMap != null){
    return ids
      .map((id) => dataMap[id])
      .whereType<MyObject>()
      .toList();
  }

  return future.map((dataMap) => ids
      .map((id) => dataMap[id])
      .whereType<MyObject>()
      .toList());
}
```